# Does ${\rm tr} A=0$ imply ${\rm tr} AB=0$ where ${\rm tr} B=2n-{\rm} tr A^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A_{(2n+1)\times(2n+1)}$ and $B_{(2n+1)\times(2n+1)}$ be two symmetric matrices of Rank $2n$.
Then

> Does ${\rm tr} A=0$ imply ${\rm tr} AB=0$ where ${\rm tr} B=2n-{\rm} tr A^2$?

**Edited (after Dietrich Burde answer):** for dim$ =3$ @Dietrich Burde conterexample shows that the answer is 'NO'. Is it correct for dim $\geq 5$?

Thanks.

Comment: You should show your work if you have tried anything.

Comment: The body question is not the same as the title

Comment: oh. yes. you are right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $A=B=diag(1,-1,0)$. Then $\operatorname{tr}(A)=0$, but $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=2$. We have $\operatorname{tr}(B)=0=2n-\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=2-2$.

Comment: Is it correct for dim $\geq 5$?

Comment: @C.F.G : yes, just add a "$1,-1$" on the diagonal for each increment on $n$. The result will be the same.